# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.** while installing gumpy

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install gumpy on my computer but I ran into this Error:
**ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.**
I use pip install gumpy code to install it and My python version is 3.6
I would be grateful if any one can help me
this is full error that is shown to me:

```
C:\Users\Hp>pip install gumpy
Collecting gumpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/41/4a43289f78b2b2bc8fa
ac7cce8fefc414932d3adbe7df90835faec182524/gumpy-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Biopython>=1.70
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/c2/ce4f74ce5dd00f02189
b3abf3cfce138f615c285d56f65d69cc994162f97/biopython-1.75-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh
l
Collecting tqdm>=4.19.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/32/5144caf0478b1f26bd9
d97f510a47336cf4ac0f96c6bc3b5af20d4173920/tqdm-4.40.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytest>=4.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/cf/711f1d887cb92c5155c
9a1eb338f1b5d2411b50e4492a3b20e4a188a22b2/pytest-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pysam>=0.15.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/e7/2dab8bb0ac739555e69
586f1492f0ff6bc4a1f8312992a83001d3deb77ac/pysam-0.15.3.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -c
 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hp\\AppData\\L
ocal\\Temp\\pip-install-ptmps6t8\\pysam\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\
\Hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ptmps6t8\\pysam\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(
tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
--egg-base 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ptmps6t8\pysam\pip-egg-in
fo'
         cwd: C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ptmps6t8\pysam\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    # pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
    # pysam: htslib mode is shared
    # pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    # pysam: htslib configure options: None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ptmps6t8\pysam\setup.py",
 line 241, in <module>
        htslib_make_options = run_make_print_config()
      File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ptmps6t8\pysam\setup.py",
 line 68, in run_make_print_config
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(["make", "-s", "print-config"])
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py
", line 356, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py
", line 423, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py
", line 729, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py
", line 1017, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running few python3 packages on my windows10 platform. I did add the path, but still did not work, then I tried a repair procedure that did not work either. Finally I had to uninstall and re install python3.7.7 [not from the wondows store, but from the official website]. That seemed to solve the issue apparently.